# Playing sounds in C#

Tags: c#, audio

I want to add sound effects to my Visual C# program. What's the simplest way to do this?

This what I wrote and did not work. 
The sound is in Desktop and I copy also to visual studio and is didnt word.
What I tried  do is when I click will be sound  effect

```
private void ShipDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    isPress = true;    
    using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("Sound\\mg42.wav"))
    {    
        player.PlaySync();
    }

}
```

Comment: the quoted duplicate indeed answers the question

Comment: Move your wav file to a 'Sounds' directory inside your project directory. You will have to navigate from 'Debug' directory to 'Sounds'. The string would be `"../../../Sounds/mg42.wav"`

Answer (score 0):

check the path "Sound\mg42.wav"
you can put mg42.wav and your exe in the same directiony, then pass "mg42.wav".

ps: double click your exe, don't run it through vs.

Comment: "Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.IO.FileNotFoundException"